# Very confused about hello world application in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I am not even sort of a Mac person. I just installed Xcode 4.2 on Lion. I want to do the Hello world tutorial to get my feet wet, but I can't even start the project the way they all suggest. I cannot find the "View based application" option in the new projects. Here is what I see:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/c46e2.png

How do I get the options that everyone else seems to have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"View-based Application" is now called "Single View Application" in Xcode 4.2.

Comment: Ahh, thank you much. I guessed page based, but it wasn't right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog, It explains all the steps in a methodical and easy-to-follow method and will get you started on how to make ur very first iOS app.

It covers the following : Interface Builder, ViewControllers, Buttons, methodes, IBActions, etc

http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/hello-world/

Hope this helps :)